# Call javascript code on page using PageAsyncTask

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous

I have two ASPX pages (`P1.aspx` and `P2.aspx`). The first (`P1.aspx`) contains a lot of JavaScript code.
How can I call all this JavaScript from another page (`P2.aspx`)?

I tried to do this using `PageAsyncTask` from code behind of `P2.aspx`, but JavaScript code (on `P1.aspx`) didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do that.

put the javascript into JS file and reference it when needed.

What you can do ( I think) is to get the HTML content of the file and then EXTRACT the JS data

### edit

try that (I dont think that it will include the inside JS  - but try it yourself)

```
WebRequest oRequest;
        WebResponse oResponse;

        oRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/");
        oResponse = oRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(oResponse.GetResponseStream());

        string pagedata = sr.ReadToEnd(); 

        pagedata+=@"sdfsdf";
```

Comment: What do you mean with EXTRACT? How can i do that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to make web request. It doesn't call javascript. :(

Comment: from my test - It does show you the inline Js code in the page.

Answer (score 1):

All javascript code you want to use on a page has to be included in that page or dynamically loaded by that page.  You cannot call code that is only in another page.

The usual way of sharing code among pages is to have a .js file that contains common code that is included in more than one page and then a .js file that contains code that is unique to each specific page (if required).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is `<!--#INCLUDE FILE="somefile.aspx" -->` but your aspx page will complain that there can be only one 'page' directive. So in order to do this properly you need to include as the previous mentiond the js files in the aspx file.
One way is makeing a master page and include all the necessary js code in there, then all pages that are loaded within the masterpage will automatically inherit the javascript included libraries.
Another way is to make an html file that includes all the libraries and then use the `<!--#INCLUDE FILE="myjslibs.html" -->` to include all your code there to each page.
So actually copy all your code in one file and then include that just one file each time in every page.